# How to find $P(B \mid T) $ and $P(B \mid T^c)$ given $P(T \mid B)$ and $P(T \mid B^ c)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

How can one calculate $P(B\mid T) $ and $P(B\mid T^c)$  given $P(T \mid B)=0.75$  and $P(T \mid B^ c)=0.15$ ?

I have found the answers. However, I have solved it in seven pages. I am getting $P(B|T)=0.75$ and $P(B|T^c)=0.09375$.

Would someone supply a better and shorter answer. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What is given about events $B$ and $T$? You know $P(T)$ but you do not know $P(B)$ so just based on how the question reads, I do not think you can establish $P(B|T)$.

Comment: Hello @MathLover, I have struggled with this question for years now. Yet I have got now in at least 4 books of statistics. So my thinking now is that it must have sufficient information. But I am not sure.

Comment: Is this exact wording of the question? Can you check and add if any text is missing?

Comment: Yes, and the same numbers as well @MathLover

Comment: Yes, thanks @MathLover, I have now found the answers to the question now. However, I have solved it in seven pages. I am getting $P(T|B)=0.75$ and $P(T|B^C)=0.09375$

Comment: @MathLover you should have $$P(T)=P(T|B)P(B)+P(T|B^c)P(B^c)$$ But, in any case, I agree with you: I don't think there's enough information here.

Comment: @MatthewPilling thank you. I see now that I wrote it without multiplying by $P(B)$ and $P(B^c)$. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @MathLover No problem. By the way, I really enjoy reading your solutions on problems in multivariable calculus, particularly with evaluating double and triple integrals. I do a lot of tutoring in these subjects, and I often find myself emulating your presentations when explaining solutions to my students.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I am glad to hear this from you. In fact you are one of those whose comments (to the problems posted on the site), I watch pretty closely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not correct, I think. And I also think the information is insufficient.

#### Setup

Let us call
$$P(B \cap T)=a$$
$$P(B - (B \cap T))=b$$
$$P(T - (B \cap T))=c$$
$$P((B \cup T)^c)=d$$

#### Information we have

$$a + b + c + d = 1\tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\frac{a}{a + b} = 0.75\tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$\frac{c}{c + d} = 0.15\tag{3}\label{3}$$

#### Goal

The target is to calculate $a/(a + c)$ and $b/(b + d)$.

From the fact that we just have three equations in 4 variables, it seems that it is not possible to get all the four variables. But it might still be possible to get the two terms we want, so I have tried to show below that that is not the case.

#### Algebraic rearrangements

From $(2)$ we have $a = 3b$

From $(3)$ we have $c = 3d/17$

Substituting these values in $(1)$ gives us
$$4b + \frac{20d}{17} = 1$$
or equivalently
$$d = \frac{(1 - 4b)17}{20}\tag{4}\label{4}$$
Using $(4)$ we can get the two desired equations in the terms of $b$.
$$\frac{a}{a + c} = \frac{3b}{3b + \frac{3(1 - 4b)}{20}}$$
$$\frac{b}{b + d} = \frac{b}{b + \frac{(1-4b)17}{20}}$$

Since there is no way to further reduce this set of equations, we cannot get the value of these two terms without knowing $b$.

You can get as many answers as you want by substituting different values of $b$. Furthermore, the two answers you give, are not compatible with one another (i.e. do not fit into this equation). Another way to see the incompatibility is as follows:

$$P(T|B)P(B) = P(B|T)P(T)$$
Since $P(T|B)=P(B|T)$, we have $P(B)=P(T)=x$.

Next, using $P(T^c|B)=1 - P(T|B) = 0.25$ and
$$P(T^c|B)x = P(B|T^c)(1 - x)$$ which gives us
$$0.25x = 0.09375(1 - x)$$
But, if we use $P(B^c|T) = 1 - P(B|T) = 0.25$ and
$$P(T|B^c)(1 -x)=P(B^c|T)x$$
we get
$$0.15(1 - x) = 0.25x$$
These two are clearly incompatible.